# Push notification in Web pages

Tags: angularjs, jsp, web, push-notification, vue.js

Can a web notification be implemented in web sites? I'm using a environment of jsp's with jquery, vue and angular.js for the front side. There's a way to implement web notifications with this environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API) to achieve this.

If you want to use [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) to push notifications from a backend, you can check the [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API)

These API are still drafts and may only work with modern browsers. Make sure you are using these API's over https.

Answer (score 0):

you can use web socket, which has integrated in Angular already.

Answer (score 0):

use for example:
https://github.com/mqttjs

then in your js:

```
    this.client = mqtt.connect(url, options);

    if(topics.length>0)
        this.client.subscribe(topics);

    this.client.on("message", (topic:any, payload:any)=>{
        console.log('CONNECTED', payload);
    });

    this.client.on("connect", function (connack: any) {
        console.log('CONNECTED', connack);
    });
```

And use some server side message broker eg: rabbitMQ or other message router

read this
https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-mqtt.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Web notification primarily targeted for Web application, client side registration and server sider processing for pushing the notification, below site has both client and server side examples -

[ServiceWorker](https://serviceworke.rs/push-clients_service-worker_doc.html)